# Solve this equation $(2x^2-3)^2=4(x-1)^2$?

Tags: roots

This is the way I solved:
[image]

What should I do next?
Should I factorize or take a t that represents something?

Comment: Why didn't you take the square root?

Comment: Is it an identical transformation? Shouldn't I reconsider +-2(x-1)

Comment: @AvZ The Square root is dangerous... use the difference of two squares $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$...

Comment: If you take $\pm$, you wouldn't lose any solutions.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Yeah, I didn't notice that. It's a much better way.

Comment: @Jp McCarthy I guess you are right. Thank you!

Comment: Either an error or a typo:  the final equation should start out $4x^4$, not $4x^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*} 0 &= (2x^2-3)^2 - 4(x-1)^2 = (2x^2-3)^2 - (2x-2)^2 \\ &= ((2x^2-3)-(2x-2))((2x^2-3)+(2x-2)) \\ &= (2x^2-2x-1)(2x^2+2x-5). \end{align*}$$  Now solve each individual quadratic; e.g., by completing the square or the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't have to factorize if you didn't expand squares before.

See this:

$(2x^2-3)^2=4(x-1)^2$

$(2x^2-3)^2-4(x-1)^2=0$

$\left[(2x^2-3)-2(x-1)\right]\left[(2x^2-3)+2(x-1)\right]=0$

$\left[2x^2-3-2x+2\right]\left[2x^2-3+2x-2\right]=0$

$(2x^2-2x-1)(2x^2+2x-5)=0$

$(x^2-x-1/2)(x^2+x-5/2)=0$

$(x^2-x+1/4-3/4)(x^2+x+1/4-11/4)=0$

$\left[(x-1/2)^2-3/4)\right]\left[(x+1/2)^2-11/4\right]=0$

so

$x = 1/2 \pm \sqrt3/2$ or $x=-1/2 \pm \sqrt{11}/2$.